# Send mail from contact form to gmail account using localhost from yii2 with phpmailer

Tags: localhost, yii2, phpmailer, contacts

I have created contact form with fields name,email,phone,message which saves in database.
I want the contact form to send email using phpmailer through localhost in Yii2. I tried following up the http://www.yiiframew.../zyx-phpmailer/ link still not able to send email.

Steps taken
1) I have downloaded phpmailer through composer.
2) I have set-up web.php in config folder as

```
'mail' => [
 'class' => 'zyx\phpmailer\Mailer',
 'viewPath' => 'yii2Basic',
 'useFileTransport' => false,
 'config' => [
 'mailer' => 'smtp',
 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 'port' => '587',
 'smtpsecure' => 'tsl',
 'smtpauth' => true,
 'username' => 'mygmail',
 'password' => '*******',
   ],
 ],
```

3) Controller action

```
public function actionCreate()
 {
    $model = new Contact();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) 
    {

        Yii::$app->mail->compose()
        ->setFrom(['mygmail' => 'My Example Message'])
        ->setTo([$model->email => $model->name])
        ->setSubject('test subject')
        ->setTextBody($model->message)
        ->send();

        $model->save();
       //return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
       return $this->redirect(['index']);

       } else {
       return $this->render('create', [
      'model' => $model,
     ]);
   }
 }
```

still the code save to my db but does not send email to gmail.

Kindly help me where I am going wrong and what should I do.

Comment: Since you're sending through a local mail server, you need to look in your mail server logs.

Comment: check $mail->ErrorInfo;

Answer (score 0):

Download php mailer from [It is used to send mail from localhost
  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer after downloading if ur system not supports phps then change phpmailer/examples->gmail.php

mail.php->it is in outside of php mailer

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'hello@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = "hello";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = 'hello@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName ='hello';
$mail->addAddress('hi@gmail.com', 'hi');

$mail->addReplyTo('hello@gmail.com', 'hello');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Using PHPMailer';
$mail->Body    = 'Hi Iam using PHPMailer library to sent SMTP mail from localhost';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

try this also [click here](https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/03/sending-mail-phpmailer.html) this is the solution